# Changing database value to false doesn't change result

Tags: php

I have this code

```
if (true == $run_user['online'] {
  $result = 'Online now!';
} else {
  $date = $run_user['lastloggedin'];
  $result = Agotime($date);
}
```

`$run_user` is to check the database by the way
So whenever I change the value in the database to false, it will still just result `"Online Now!"` Instead of saying what it's supposed to say, which is for example `1 hour ago.`

Comment: Because they are strings and not Boolean values. As a result they are always true when using loose comparisons (`==`).

Comment: @JohnConde Wow, didn't realise it was that simple, well, thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

@John Conde had it right, but I can expound on what is actually happening.

In PHP there are certain things that will be left for interpretation. Boolean checks are one of those things. Here is a couple lists of things that will be interpreted in a Boolean check:

**These will be interpreted as TRUE**

- Boolean true, of course
- Non-empty strings
- Any non-zero integer
- A function, object or array

**These will be interpreted as FALSE**

- Boolean false
- The integer 0
- An empty string
- null
- The not (!) character followed by an interpreted true or Boolean true

These might be confusing at times, but the best thing to do for checking is to make sure you know what type of variables you are passing into the conditional. Sometimes it may be useful to use a strict comparator like so:

```
if(true === $variable){ ... }
```

The third equal sign will tell PHP to only interpret this as true/false if it is EXACTLY what I am comparing it to. So `$variable = true;` would work, but `$variable = 1;` would not. Without the strict comparator, both versions would work. This issue comes into play a lot when you are working with integers where `0` needs to be interpreted as `true` and `null` should be `false`.